# Screenshot using Win CE6

Tags: bitmap, windows-ce, screenshot

Is there a way that I could use to take a screenshot from a windows CE6 application? I have an existing application and I would like to take screenshots from my app.I need to get a screenshot request activated from the app itself and save the screenshot to a predefined location. I have been looking online for answers and haven't really found anything. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

I have managed to get something up and running but it doesnt give the whole bitmap. Instead it only gives the lower half of the bitmap. Any suggestions on where this is going wrong?

**Screenshot Code**:

```
HWND DesktopHwnd = ::GetDesktopWindow();
   RECT DesktopParams;
   HDC DevC = ::GetDC(DesktopHwnd);
   ::GetWindowRect(DesktopHwnd,&DesktopParams);
   DWORD Width = DesktopParams.right - DesktopParams.left;
   DWORD Height = DesktopParams.bottom - DesktopParams.top;

   // get the device context of the screen
   HDC hScreenDC = CreateDC(_T("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);     
   // and a device context to put it in
   HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

   int x = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
   int y = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);

   // maybe worth checking these are positive values
   HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, x, y);

   // get a new bitmap
   HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

   BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, Width, Height, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
   hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);

   // now your image is held in hBitmap. You can save it or do whatever with it
   HWND hwnd = DesktopHwnd;
   PBITMAPINFO pbi; 
   HBITMAP hBMP = hBitmap;
   HDC hDC = DevC;
   HANDLE hf;                  // file handle  
   BITMAPFILEHEADER hdr;       // bitmap file-header  
   PBITMAPINFOHEADER pbih;     // bitmap info-header
   DWORD dwTotal;              // total count of bytes  
   DWORD cb;                   // incremental count of bytes  
   BYTE *hp;                   // byte pointer  
   DWORD dwTmp; 
   int ret = 0;

   pbi = CreateBitmapInfoStruct(NULL, hBMP);
   if(pbi == NULL)
   {
   }
   pbih = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER) pbi; 

   RGBQUAD *rgbq;
   rgbq = pbi->bmiColors;
   PALETTEENTRY pe[256];
   GetSystemPaletteEntries(hDC, 0, pbih->biClrUsed, pe);
   for(DWORD i = 0; i < pbih->biClrUsed; i++)
   {
     rgbq[i].rgbRed = pe[i].peRed;
     rgbq[i].rgbBlue = pe[i].peBlue;
     rgbq[i].rgbGreen = pe[i].peGreen;
     rgbq[i].rgbReserved = 0;
   }

   // CE5.0 + CE6.0
   HBITMAP h = CreateDIBSection(hScreenDC, pbi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **)&hp, NULL, 0);
   if(h == NULL)
   {
     goto close_bmp;
   }
   SelectObject(hMemoryDC, h);
   BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, Width, Height, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

   // Create the .BMP file.  
   hf = CreateFile(_T("\\FlashDisk\\image1.bmp"),GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,(DWORD) 0, NULL, 
                  CREATE_ALWAYS, 
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
                (HANDLE) NULL);
   if (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
   {
     goto close_bmp;
   }
   hdr.bfType = 0x4D42;        // 0x42 = "B" 0x4d = "M"  
   // Compute the size of the entire file.  
   hdr.bfSize = (DWORD) (sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + pbih->biSizeImage); 
   hdr.bfReserved1 = 0; 
   hdr.bfReserved2 = 0; 

   // Compute the offset to the array of color indices.  
   hdr.bfOffBits = (DWORD) sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + 
                 pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed 
                 * sizeof (RGBQUAD); 

   // Copy the BITMAPFILEHEADER into the .BMP file.  
   if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPVOID) &hdr, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 
     (LPDWORD) &dwTmp,  NULL)) 
   {
     goto close_bmp;
   }

   // Copy the BITMAPINFOHEADER and RGBQUAD array into the file.  
   if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPVOID) pbih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) 
               + pbih->biClrUsed * sizeof (RGBQUAD), 
               (LPDWORD) &dwTmp, ( NULL)))
   {
   }

   // Copy the array of color indices into the .BMP file.  
   dwTotal = cb = pbih->biSizeImage; 

   //hp = lpBits;     
   if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPSTR) hp, (int) cb, (LPDWORD) &dwTmp,NULL)) 
   {
     goto close_bmp;
   }

   close_bmp:
   // Close the .BMP file.  
   if(hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
     if (!CloseHandle(hf)) 
     {
        int xyz = 2;
        xyz = 3;
     }
     else
     {
         ret = 1;
     }
   }

   if(h != NULL)
     DeleteObject(h);
   if(pbi != NULL)
   {
     free(pbi);
   }

   // clean up
   if(hMemoryDC != NULL)
      DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
   DeleteDC(hScreenDC);
```

Cheers.

Comment: Have you actually looked online? I did a google search for 'windows ce6 screenshot' and turned up plenty of results.

Comment: Not a programming question?

Comment: It is a programming question. I need to get a screenshot request activated from the app itself and save the screenshot to a predefined location.

Comment: Edit your question to include the provisions that you have stated in your comment. As it was originally, it looked like a request to find a piece of software. See also [how to ask a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are x,y,Width,Height values the values you're expecting?  It seems you stumble on some of my modified code.

Comment: yes x,y, Width and Height are the values I require. However, I am getting a black screen dump rather than my screenshot. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to finally get a screenshot working. This may help others later in the future to take screenshots from within Win CE6 Apps. Hope this helps others.

```
void MyScreenshotFunction::Screenshot()
       {
          HWND DesktopHwnd = ::GetDesktopWindow();
          RECT DesktopParams;
          HDC DevC = ::GetDC(DesktopHwnd);
          ::GetWindowRect(DesktopHwnd,&DesktopParams);
          DWORD Width = DesktopParams.right - DesktopParams.left;
          DWORD Height = DesktopParams.bottom - DesktopParams.top;

          DWORD FileSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)+(sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)+1*(Width*Height*4));
          char *BmpFileData = (char*)GlobalAlloc(0x0040,FileSize);

          PBITMAPFILEHEADER BFileHeader = (PBITMAPFILEHEADER)BmpFileData;
          PBITMAPINFOHEADER  BInfoHeader = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER)&BmpFileData[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];

          BFileHeader->bfType = 0x4D42; // BM
          BFileHeader->bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);
          BFileHeader->bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

          BITMAPINFO bmi;
          ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
          bmi.bmiHeader.biSize            =   sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
          bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth           =   Width;
          bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight          =   Height;
          bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes          =   1;
          bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount        =   24;
          bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression     =   BI_RGB;
          bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage       =   bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth * abs(bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight) * 3;

          unsigned char *BitsRGB=0;
          HDC CaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
          HBITMAP CaptureBitmap = CreateDIBSection(DevC, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&BitsRGB, NULL, 0);
          SelectObject(CaptureDC,CaptureBitmap);
          BitBlt(CaptureDC, 0, 0, Width, Height, DevC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

          BITMAPFILEHEADER hdr;       // bitmap file-header
          hdr.bfType = 0x4d42;        // 0x42 = "B" 0x4d = "M"  
          // Compute the size of the entire file.  
          hdr.bfSize = (DWORD) (sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + bmi.bmiHeader.biSize + bmi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
          // Compute the offset to the array of color indices.  
          hdr.bfOffBits = (DWORD) sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + bmi.bmiHeader.biSize + bmi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed * sizeof (RGBQUAD);
          hdr.bfReserved1 = 0; 
          hdr.bfReserved2 = 0;

          DWORD Junk;
          HANDLE FH = CreateFile(_T("\\Destination.bmp"),GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,CREATE_ALWAYS,0,0);

          // Copy the BITMAPFILEHEADER into the .BMP file.  
          WriteFile(FH, (LPVOID) &hdr, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),(LPDWORD) &Junk,  NULL);

          // Copy the BITMAPINFOHEADER and RGBQUAD array into the file.  
          WriteFile(FH, (LPVOID) &(bmi.bmiHeader), sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + bmi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed * sizeof (RGBQUAD), 
             (LPDWORD) &Junk, ( NULL));

          // Copy the array of color indices into the .BMP file.  
          WriteFile(FH, (LPSTR) BitsRGB, (int) bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, (LPDWORD) &Junk,NULL);
          CloseHandle(FH);
          ReleaseDC(DesktopHwnd, DevC);
          GlobalFree(BmpFileData);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could start cerdisp.exe (e.g. \windows\cerdisp.exe) on the device and connect from the desktop pc via cerhost (\WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\BIN\I386\cerhost.exe).
Then use a PC screenshot tool to capture the cerhost-image.

Greetings.

Comment: Dont need a PC to take screenshot. I want the CE Application to take a screenshot of itself programatically.

Comment: Ok - misunderstood your question (or did you edit it?).

Comment: I have added my Code after your answer.