# How to do screen capture on Mobile Computer Handheld

Tags: screenshot, screen-capture, motorola, windows-embedded-compact, handheld

I'm currently developing handheld program on Motorola model MC9200 Windows embedded handheld 6.5. For now I need to do the User Manual documentation provided with screen shots.

I've googled about how to do the print screen on the handheld mobile, most of the results returned is 3rd party software tools. And those tools require Active Sync. Somehow Active sync is only available for Windows Vista or previous version.

May I know is there any other way to do screen shots of my program on the handheld mobile?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for a ready-to-run, third-party tool, or a piece of source code in say C/C++/C# to generate a screenshot? Or would either do?

Comment: I'm looking for a ready-to-run tool to generate a screenshot, it's like what we do usually in desktop using "prtscn" button to capture the current screen. But the handheld itself doesn't have a button like that.

Comment: In that case I would suggest using one of the third-party tools that you have already found, with Windows Mobile Device Center to replace ActiveSync on the desktop

Comment: @JessieChua For others like me looking for a programmed way to extract an image from the screen. there is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234308/screenshot-using-win-ce6); or using this tool **cczoom.exe** (Remote Zoom In), located in "Program Files (x86)\CE Remote Tools\5.01\bin" that come together with Visual Studio 2008 with SP1 which you can save bitmap remotely.

Answer (score 2):

I decided not to spend time on trial and error for the programs. For now my workaround to get the program screenshots is using the emulator in the VS studio.

Comment: Believe it or not - this was a highly valuable "answer" for me! I have done the same for the time being. Not worth the time spent on trial and error as stated in this answer,

Answer (score 0):

ActiveSync has been replaced by [Windows Mobile Device Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile_Device_Center) (WMDC) in more recent versions of desktop Windows.

Third-party tools that require ActiveSync should work equally fine with WMDC.